# Web Site deployment in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I am working on a web application which has around 40 pages. We have separate business and DB layer. But there are still few simple business logic in code behind (CS) page of each aspx file. So when there is any change in that code behind, it lead to complete re-deployment of whole project. Is there any option where I could re-deploy only the corresponding code behind and aspx page alone?

**Note :** We copy the web contents to the virtual directory for each deployment

Answer (score 0):

Not from Visual Studio, it does a complete publish each time.  You can do this manually though (copy over the files that have changed as long as they are not part of a compiled DLL for your site).  IIS will recompile the site on first request, each subsequent request will use the newly compiled DLL for your site.

Comment: This is fine for aspx change but when it comes to code behind cs ?